# Soundcloud API returning 502 error when uploading track

Tags: api, soundcloud, http-status-codes

I'm using the Soundcloud API wrapper for PHP to upload some tracks.
The app worked fine for years until a few days.

Now I'm getting a HTTP 100 code followed by a HTTP 502 error.

This is the request:

```
Array
(
    [CURLOPT_HEADER] => 1
    [CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER] => 1
    [CURLOPT_USERAGENT] => PHP-SoundCloud/2.3.2
    [CURLOPT_POST] => 1
    [CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] => Array
    (
        [track[title]] => Boris - Like Water (Original Mix) [Alleanza]
        [track[description]] => <p>It is said that there is something in the New York air that makes sleep useless and these night-loving cuts from Boris sustain the fact of his own city. Bottom heavy might be the ideal definition for these showpieces but when we secure work of this calibre to the label throwing light upon words would be a violation of what is regarded as sacred to new age techno for the reason that interpretation to such elegance should be prevailed at the given time of function.</p>
        [track[asset_data]] => @/home/cubelab/platform/labels/alleanza/ALLE043/BORIS_-_Like_Water_-_ALLEANZA.mp3
        [track[sharing]] => private
        [track[tag_list]] => "Boris" "Like Water" "Original Mix" "Techno" "Alleanza"
        [track[genre]] => Techno
        [track[track_type]] => original
        [track[downloadable]] => 
        [track[release]] => ALLE043
        [track[release_day]] => 04
        [track[release_month]] => 08
        [track[release_year]] => 2014
        [track[purchase_url]] => http://www.beatport.com/release/like-water-the-master/1340844
        [track[artwork_data]] => @/home/cubelab/platform/labels/alleanza/ALLE043/ALLE043.jpg
        [track[label_name]] => Alleanza
    )

    [CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER] => Array
    (
        [0] => Accept: application/json
        [1] => Authorization: OAuth *-*****-*******-****************
    )
)
```

This is the response from the server:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue

HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Fri, 08 Aug 2014 09:51:03 GMT
Server: ECS (ams/4989)
Content-Length: 349

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
         "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
    <head>
    <title>502 - Bad Gateway</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>502 - Bad Gateway</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

It seems like a Soundcloud server error, and I don't know how to do any further debugging.

Comment: We've been getting tons and tons of 502 errors from the SoundCloud API also. Haven't been able to upload anything at all since the 6th of August. Over 450 attempts to send to the API have failed. I've contacted SoundCloud but they're not being massively helpful so far!

Answer (score 0):

had same problem. same timeframe. kept checking every day manually. and OMG, just now my script worked 100% fine. and it should work for you now too. can you confirm?

so to answer your question: *just give it time and all will come back to normal operation*.. heh.. that's soundcloud for you, german engineering and such...  it's very moody and sometimes scripts that worked for years stop working. and always just for a few days...

Comment: Thats what i call regression bugs introduction ;)